# Web2py multi-digit value from dropdown gets treated as a list of values

Tags: forms, list, web2py

I have an SQLFORM.factory field:

```
Field('course', requires=IS_IN_SET(course_query, multiple=True), widget=SQLFORM.widgets.multiple.widget),
```

that gets its contents from a query:

```
course_query = external_db.executesql("SELECT course_id, course_title FROM course")
```

I want the user to be able to select one or more courses, which they can. Upon submit, the course_id(s) they submitted are captured by:

```
courses = request.vars.course
```

then I loop through the returned course_id's and insert them into a table:

```
    if form.process().accepted:
    for course in courses:
        external_db.enrolment.insert(student_id=student, course_id=course)
    response.flash = 'Record saved'
```

This works fine when the user selects more than one course. Each submitted record gets inserted into the database with the correct course_id. But if the user selects only one course, which happens to have a 2-digit ID, only the first digit gets inserted.

I have found that if a single 2-digit course_id value is submitted Web2py treats it as a list, with each digit as an individual element.

How do I make it treat double-digit values from request.vars as a single value instead of a list of values?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer values returned from the browser are actually strings, and when you have just a single value selected, you end up with a single string rather than a list of strings. In Python, when you iterate over a string, you iterate over the individual characters in the string. In this case, a double-digit value is just a two-character string, so your `for` loop will run once for each digit.

A simple solution is to use `form.vars.course` instead of `request.vars.course`. The former will be a list even when only a single value has been selected, so you will be iterating over a list containing a single item rather than iterating over a two-character string.

Note, `form.vars` will not be populated with the processed form values until after you have called `form.process()`, so you may need to adjust the order of your code.

As an aside, there is no need to specify the `widget` argument, as you will get that widget automatically by virtue of using the `IS_IN_SET(..., multiple=True)` validator.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony, you're right again. I remember you drawing my attention to form.var instead of request.vars for values returned from forms, I'll remember that in future.